# Ifelse conditional colours ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here, why are colours not properly assigned? 
I want to avoid creating a new variable!!
Many thanks!

```
sepal_values <- c(7.3, 7.0, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 5.7)

ggplot(data = filter(iris, !Species == "setosa"),
       aes(y = Petal.Length, x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = ifelse(Sepal.Length %in% sepal_values, "firebrick", "dodgerblue3")))
```

[image: ggplot2_conditional_colour]

Comment: You could use `scale_color_identity()`, if you want.

Comment: Why do you say that colors are not properly assigned ?

Comment: @jazurro. Yes, that makes the job, thank you!

Comment: @user3262756 Pleasure to help.